# Setting up something that is limited to a value within an array?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

I am currently working on a project and I'm not entirely sure how to do this but I want to have an if statement that has something along the lines of this

```
if(a != b[]){
    printf("Use another value!");
}
```

Where b[] is any value within the array. So for example if I have 100 values and what the user inputted was not any of those then it would then print "Use another value!"

I thought I should specify that I am doing this is C

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which language are you using ?

Comment: I am doing this in C. Edited for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate thorugh the loop and check it's value

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(b);i++)
{
   if(a!=b[i]
   {
    printf("Use another value");
    break;
  }
}
```

i guess its done in this way.I have not really used C in a long time.

Comment: That would yield a whole lot of "Use another value"'s but I can work off of that thanks!

Comment: Did u run it?.I think the use of break should get you out of loop.

Answer (score 0):

in C# you can go

ArrayVariable.Contains(object)

Comment: I am actually doing this is C. I probably should have specified.